# Locking Documents whose Geospatial Index is Located within a Bounding Box?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents:

```
{ 
  location: {
    lon: 3.14,
    lat: 2.72
  },
  value: 0.71
}
```

A geospatial index is defined on the content of the location-key.

Is it possible to lock a bounding box regarding that geospatial index?

That means no documents in that bbox may be added, removed or changed?

Does MongoDB provide means for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no mechanism for locking documents. You will have to implement the lock at the application level, say by adding a `locked : true` field to all the documents in the bounding box and then requiring `locked : false` in updates/removes and checking that inserts don't fall within the box. Just be aware that MongoDB doesn't have transactions, so if you perform a `multi : true` update concurrently with other operations, some documents could be seen as unlocked that are part of the update but that have yet to be affected by the update.